# How to check user's other time period percentile?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues, user-rank

At the user's info, there is a percentile status like

> top 3% this year

Is there a way how to check other (week, month, quarter, all time) periods percentile?

Answer (score 6):

You just need to do a little bit of math.

Go to the rankings page. Select whichever rank you want. I have selected Quarter Rank.

> [image]

Now, note your own rank. Here's mine.

> [image]

Also, note the total number of users.

> [image]

Finally, calculate your percentile.

> 100 * (81,502 - 79) / 81,502 = ~99% or top 1%

However, this is not the percentile that is shown on the profile.

If you look at the sidebar, you will see :

> [image]

So, to find the equivalent percentile that the system uses, we need to correct for this. We need the total number of users having reputation greater than 200 which can be easily seen on the sidebar under Total Reputation.

> [image]

So, now calculating the system percentile.

> 100 * (544 - 79) / 544 = ~85% or top 15%

Comment: Nice answer, but this is the way I do it now. Do I really need to compute like this everytime? I can live without this, I just wanted to know.

Comment: @JanTuroň To the best of my knowledge, yes. Other option is SEDE, but I wouldnt recommend doing that, as the query may be expensive.

Answer (score 2):

You could work it out... You can type a name in [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow) to find the rank of a user. If you don't type in a name there are buttons at the bottom which allow you to find the last entry e.g.

[image]...

Divide the rank by the total and multiply by 100 and you've got your percentage. Other tabs allow you to repeat this for week, month etc.

Comment: litter error can be occur as last page not necessarily contains 30 user

Comment: I do it this way now, but it would be nice if the user profile contained all five time periods percentils to save me this effort.

Comment: It amounts to the same thing. Percentile = percentage in common English usage. And even mathematically 100 - (total - x) / total = x / total