# Relative value of reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation, reputation-leagues

Is there a way to find out the percentile (in the reputation distribution) of a person's reputation on a specific site?

The actual meaning of, say, 5k reputation, is different depending on the specific site, but the percentile (e.g., 50% - median - vs 5% - i.e., 95% of users have smaller reputation) should be more comparable.

EDIT: The information is *almost* available as [rank](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow) but should be as percent in addition to rank (being in top 1,000 out of 10k is very different than 1,000 out of 100k).

Also, I think the percentile should be appended to raw reputation everywhere, i.e., instead of `foo 1234` it should be `foo 1234 (33%)` if 33% of users on the site have reputation over 33%.

Comment: Percentile of what?

Comment: @H2CO3: position in the distribution

Comment: Are you looking for http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow and the like?

Comment: Your overall rank on SO is #6650 of 139865 total. That places you in the top 4.7% overall (this data is already in the users tab).

Comment: @H2CO3: not quite, see edit

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2231/158428

Comment: @TravisJ: http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow says "2,290,706 total users"

Comment: why downvote? there are similar questions, but they are talking about absolute ranks, not percentiles

Comment: @sds - Sure, but how many of them have 1 reputation? You asked for what your percentile was in relation to reputation. Rank is based on reputation. So it wouldn't really make sense that of 2,290,706 users there would be 2,290,706 ranks.

Comment: @sds As it says at the bottom of the league page "users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues". So when SO shows you a ranking as a percentage, it's relative to the number of users with 200+ rep.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187326/158428

Answer (score 7):

On Stack Overflow at least, you should see something like this:

[image]

Comment: Well, I do not have this indicator on my personal page on Stack Overflow. I think this comes only if one has earned some minimal reputation.

Comment: @StefanBollmann you need to have a minimum of 200 rep to be tracked in the reputation leagues.  That is why it doesn't show for you.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The value that is shown on that summary tab will vary. It could be your percentage ranking in the current week, month, quarter, or year - I think it depends on which timespan gives you the best result.